# How to convert a String to TimeZone : Android

Tags: java, android, string, timezone

I am having a String `myString = "Asia/kolkata";`

I need to set `TimeZone.setDefault(myString);`

**I have tried as mentioned above. But String cannot be given in TimeZone parameter.**

How to set this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use [`TimeZone.getTimeZone(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29) to get the time zone, then you can set that as the default.

Comment: @Dray: accepting the answer is the best way of thanking the helper.

Comment: @Umesh : you are absolutely correct.Immediately I check Mark the Answer. Stack Overflow asks me to wait for 12 minutes to Say thanks to Jon Skeet :)Still 5 Min left over.